# Spark dataframe left join should add join with default row instead of null on right side

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, left-join

I am trying to left join two dataframes in Pyspark on one common column. If the value of common column is not present in right dataframe then null values are inserted. Instead of null values I want it to join with a default row in right dataframe. Is it possible to achieve this?

```
df1 = df1.join(df2, [df1.id == df2.channel_id], "left")
df1.select('channel_id', 'channel_name').show()
```

My code prints null, null for rows where there is no match. Instead I want it to match to row with id = 0 which is default value.

Comment: so essentially you want to replace the `Null` values with the default values from `id=0`? That could be easier achieved than another join

Comment: How many columns do you need to set there?

Comment: @NeilZ There can be any number of columns. What I want here that instead of Null values for all column in right dataframe, I want values from default row in right dataframe. In my case I have default column with id = 0.

Comment: Add a [mcve] with a small sample of your data and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

1. This can be one way to achieve what you want.

(1) First let's create 2 sample DataFrames, and `left` join them to get `df_join`.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a'), (2,'b'),(3, 'f'),(4,'c'),(5, 'd')], ['id', 'name1'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'aaa'), (2,'bb'),(7, 'ff'),(4,'cc'),(8,'mm'), (10,'kk')], ['channel_id', 'channel_name'])
df1.show()
df2.show()
df_join = df1.join(df2, [df1.id == df2.channel_id], "left")
df_join.orderBy('id').show()
```

The DataFrames are shown as below. You can see rows with `id` 3 and 5 are not present in `df2`, so their corresponding values in columns: `channel_id` and `channel_name` are `null`. We want to fill them with corresponding values in row with `id==1`.

```
------ df1 ------
+---+-----+
| id|name1|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  2|    b|
|  3|    f|
|  4|    c|
|  5|    d|
+---+-----+

------ df2 ------
+----------+------------+
|channel_id|channel_name|
+----------+------------+
|         1|         aaa|
|         2|          bb|
|         7|          ff|
|         4|          cc|
|         8|          mm|
|        10|          kk|
+----------+------------+

------ df_join ------
+---+-----+----------+------------+
| id|name1|channel_id|channel_name|
+---+-----+----------+------------+
|  1|    a|         1|         aaa|
|  2|    b|         2|          bb|
|  3|    f|      null|        null|
|  4|    c|         4|          cc|
|  5|    d|      null|        null|
+---+-----+----------+------------+
```

(2) Next, pick up the default row you want to fall back on, here I just used the row with `id==1`.

```
default_row = df_join.where(df_join['id']==1).select('channel_id', 'channel_name').take(1)[0].asDict()
print('----- default_row: {} ------'.format(default_row))
```

The output shows what the default values we are going to use:

```
----- default_row: {'channel_id': 1, 'channel_name': 'aaa'} ------
```

(3) Now we can fill all the Nulls using `fillna` on each column

```
for k, v in default_row.items():
    df_join = df_join.fillna(v, subset=k)
df_join.orderBy('id').show()
```

The final DataFrame looks like below. The nulls are successfully filled.

```
+---+-----+----------+------------+
| id|name1|channel_id|channel_name|
+---+-----+----------+------------+
|  1|    a|         1|         aaa|
|  2|    b|         2|          bb|
|  3|    f|         1|         aaa|
|  4|    c|         4|          cc|
|  5|    d|         1|         aaa|
+---+-----+----------+------------+
```